# visual studio - refreshing from source control - annoying dialogs

Tags: visual-studio

Whenever I refresh from source control and go back into Visual Studio it gives me a bunch of dialogs about refreshing projects and "file has changed" that I have to click on.  Even though some of them have a checkbox like "yes to all" I still have to click on quite a few of them.  Is there any way to avoid this annoyance?

Answer (score 0):

You could just close the solution, refresh your project from source control, and then reopen it once the update has completed.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but that's really slow

Answer (score 0):

What type of source control are you using? Visual Studio is pretty flexible about using source control directly from the IDE. If I can help you set up source control you might not have to open two seperate applications to complete your check in's and check out's.